# Getting an instance of a subclass from a different class

Tags: java, polymorphism, instance, subclass, slick2d

I am writing a game using the slick 2D engine and my own entity engine to work out the details of a 2D side scroller

The way my code currently works is like this:

Entity class holds entity information. It can have an Ability, something like Animation or sound or movement. All abilities are subclasses of an abstract class called Ability.

I have a method in the Entity class where I wish to get an instance of a specific ability, so that I can use its methods:

```
 public Ability getAbility(String id) {
    for(Ability abil : ablitites) {
        if(abil.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(id)) {
            return abil;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

However, this only returns a specific instance of the superclass, Ability. I wish to get an instance of the subclass from a different package or class.

A sample of code that does this would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand your question but I think you should take a look to [Casting](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-object-typecasting).

I think you should use your code like this:
(Of course, I have no clue of your design, so I'm guessing a bit)

```
Ability ability = getAbility("moveLeft");
if (ability instanceof MoveAbility)
{
    // Right here, we know it IS a MoveAbility because we checked it with
    // instanceof

    // So, we can cast it to a MoveAbility.
    MoveAbility moveAbility = (MoveAbility) ability;
    moveAbility.execute();
}
```

Comment: this is great. I thought about this, but I wasn't sure if instanceof is a no-no in java or not. But this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is already doing what you want.  If your `ablitites` collection already holds instances of `Animation`, `Sound`, and `Movement` objects, then that's what your method will return. It just returns them through an `Ability` *reference*.  It can't return an instance of the superclass `Ability` since that's an abstract class.  You should be able to call the common methods declared in `Ability` and see that the objects returned by your method behave as instances of the specific subclasses that you request.

Comment: well thats helpful, but it does not allow me to access subclass methods from a different class, only the common ones

Comment: @Young_Maker Yes, you'd have to cast the object to the correct type as soon as you get it from that method (when you still know from the `id` string what type it really is.

Comment: yep, thats what Martijn Courteaux said.