# Get subclass instance from list of superclasses or interfaces

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, subclass

([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640171/getting-an-instance-of-a-subclass-from-a-different-class) question is similar to mine but I felt that they were different enough that I could create a new one).

Basically in my small 3D game all of my entities are made up of many different components, one for textures, one for movement etc. All of these sub-components inherit from the interface "Component". Up until now I've used methods like this;

```
public MovementComponent getMovementComponent() {
    for (Component c : components) {
        if (c instanceof MovementComponent)
            return (MovementComponent) c;
    }

    return null;
}
```

To get an instance of a certain component. But now I wish to change this to a more general method that can get any type of component from my list of components. I tested doing something like this;

```
public Component getComponentType(Class component) {
    for (Component c : components) {
        if (c.getClass() == component)
            return c.getClass().cast(c);
    }

    return null;
}
```

But even though I cast the result this always returns an """instance""" of the interface, never an instance of a sub-component, which means I still have to cast it to the appropriate type. Basically I wish for a method that can:

1. Iterate through a collection.
2. Find a specific sub-class.
3. Return the instance of that sub-class.

I feel like I'm on the right track here but I can't get it to work. Thanks for your responses and feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need something like

```
public <T extends Component> T getComponentType(Class<T> component) {
    ...
    return (T) c;
}
```

Method declaration tells that it will return a component of the same type passed in parameters.

Call it like this:

```
MovingComponent mc = smth.getComponentType(MovingComponent.class);
```

Comment: Works great. But Eclipse gives me a warning that it's an unchecked cast - what does this mean and is this something I should handle (if so, how? Suppress warning?)?

Comment: The warning is due to the unsafe typecast. See my answer for a better solution - the method header is the same but the cast is done using the `cast` method.

Comment: @Charanor unchecked cast warning is shown because compiler does not know that you performed == check. But since you did that, casting is absolutely safe and you can ignore it with @SupressWarning("unchecked") method annotation

Comment: @Charanor you can also use cast method as you did in your example

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers guys. Although turns out the casting didn't work unless I did what @Marwin did in his answer (.cast(c)). I wish I could accept both of your answers!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a generic parameter, something like this:

```
public <C extends Component> C getComponentType(Class<C> subclass) {
    for (Component c : components) {
        if (subclass.isInstance(c))
            return subclass.cast(c);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Thank to `isInstance`, this also finds any further subclass of the given parameter.